# How to make TS make an inference on interface types

Tags: typescript

I have this object that I created into my React application.

`type Props = { message: MessageTypes | MessageImgTypes; showTimeStamp: boolean; }`

Assuming that MessageTypes is the following :

`interface MessageTypes { text: string; };`

and that MessageImgTypes is the following :

`interface MessageImgTypes { text?: string; textImg : string; };`

When I try to access textImg property of MessageImgTypes, I get an error telling me that :
Property 'textImg' does not exist on type 'MessageTypes | MessageImgTypes'
Though this is a union, so it should exist on the MessageImgType since I've declared it in there.
I thought about doing Narrowing to make 2 branches but typeof and instanceof do not apply on these interfaces.

Comment: Since it is a union it is either `MessageTypes` or `MessageImgTypes`, thus we get the error since there is no `textImg` in the `MessageTypes`. you can use `in` operator for narrowing: `if('textImg' in message) {}`

Answer (score 2):

The union means that `message` will be either `MessageTypes` or `MessageImgTypes` and since there is no `'textImg'` in the `MessageTypes`, and thus you get the error.

There are several approaches that we can take.

1. Use the `in` operator:
   With the `in` operator we can check whether there is a key inside of the object, which will help the compiler to narrow the type:

```
if('textImg' in message) {
   message.textImg // no error
}
```

2. [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)
   The discriminated union is a union where each member has one common property with a unique value. Checking the value of that field will also narrow the type, but will require changes in the shape of the interfaces:

```
interface MessageTypes { text: string; type: 'one' };

interface MessageImgTypes { text?: string; textImg : string; type: 'two' };

if(message.type === 'two') {
   message.textImg // no error
}
```

3. Use a custom type guard:

```
const isMessageImgTypes = (arg: MessageTypes | MessageImgTypes): arg is MessageImgTypes => {
   return 'textImg' in arg;
}
```